# Import a function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I´ve written a function in which i say which number is odd. And then in a second function, I want to say which number is odd from a given list.
So my question is:

How can I include the data file for the first function, e.g. odd.hs, in the second data file, e.g. oddNbrs.hs. to use the first function in the second function ?

For example in C I have "include" as you know. Exists something like "include" in haskell, too? Or?

edit: Both files are of course in the same directory. Is that enough, when I mention the name first function in the second function, or should I do a different thing ?

Comment: please consider giving code examples, when you ask questions

Answer (score 5):

I think the keyword you are looking for is `module`.

file: `Odd.hs`

```
module Odd where

isOdd :: Int -> Bool
isOdd x = x `rem` 2 /= 0
```

file: `Even.hs`

```
module Even where

import Odd

isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven = not isOdd
```

file: `Numbers.hs`

```
module Numbers where

import Odd
import Even

theNumbers :: [Int]
theNumbers = [1..100]

theOddNumbers  = filter isOdd theNumbers
theEvenNumbers = filter isEven theNumbers
```

---

Or, more elegantly in one module.

file: `Predicates.hs`

```
module Predicates where

isEven ...
isOdd
```

file: `Main.hs`

```
module Main where

import Predicates (isEven)

numbers = [1..100]

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ print $ filter isEven numbers
```

Comment: In addition there exists the CPP(=C-pre-processor) and the FFI (=Foreign function interface), which you might find, when you are looking for `include` and `haskell` - I don't think it relates to your problem!

Comment: hi, first of all, thank you for your answer. It is also possible to have both functions in one file ? is that possible?

Comment: if you get errors - it often helps if you provide them - otherwise one has to guess what your problem is which is tedious and unnerving. And unnerved people are less likely to answer questions ;-)

Comment: @user3097712 Note that there are some naming restrictions on modules. Their names *must* start with capital letters, and the corresponding file *must* be named that name + `.hs` (unless you are using Literate Haskell, but that's a bit out of scope for this question.) In particular you cannot name them exactly the same as the functions, since function names must start with lower case. The only exception is the Main module file, which doesn't need to be named the same since it isn't imported from elsewhere.